# Execution halted - R command line parameters

Tags: r, parameter-passing, commandargument

I have a R script and I would like to pass some filenames/parameters to my Rscript and to execute it from a terminal. I used this command:

```
fileA='aaaa.txt'
fileB='bbbb.txt'
n=100
string='hello'
R CMD BATCH --vanilla '--args $fileA $fileB $n $string' Rscript_file.R
```

I added this line in my Rscript_file.R file:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingonly=TRUE)
```

but I got this error:

```
> args <- commandArgs(trailingonly=TRUE)
Error in commandArgs(trailingonly = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (trailingonly = TRUE)
Execution halted
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: you use the wrong argument. It needs to be with a capital 'O'. commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

Comment: The argument is `trailingOnly` (with a capital O).

Comment: thansk a lot! but it seems it doesn't recognised the strings/value of each variable.
I got this error:

'In file(file, "r") : cannot open file '$fileA': No such file or directory'
Any adieas?

Comment: That error seems to be about something different than the current question and the current question lacks the details to debug it. Therefore, I'm voting to close this as a typo question.